# pointer to std::list that have non pointer elements on c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm new in c++ world and I've this doubt.
If I want to define a pointer to a std::list of MyClass element like this:

```
std::list<MyClass> * myList=new list<MyClass>();
```

and, after, I add 2 instances of MyClass to myList.

The 2 instances of MyClass are allocated on Stack Memory and myList on Heap, is it true? 
So if the 2 instances go out of scope, myList lose all element inside it?

It is not clear to me the **memory management** in this situation. 
So I test this code:

```
list<A> * myList=new list<A>();
{
    A a1(4);
    A a2(1);
    myList->push_back(a1);
    myList->push_back(a2);
    for(A& a:*myList)
        cout << a.getVar()<<endl;
}
    cout <<"a1 and a2 go out of scope"<<endl;
    for(A& a:*myList)
        cout << a.getVar()<<endl;
```

where A class code is:

```
class A{
    private:
        int var;
    public:
        A(int x){this->var=x;}
        int getVar(){ return var;}
};
```

And the output is:

```
4
1
a1 and a2 go out of scope
4
1
```

Comment: Standard containers contain copies of the elements you put into them.

Comment: `std::list<MyClass> * myList=new list<MyClass>();` is pretty much never what you want to do.  `std::list<MyClass>  myList;` is normally what you need

Comment: *So if the 2 instances go out of scope, myList lose all element inside it?* No, it won't. `std::list::push_back()` makes a copy of the object you pass. The copy is held in the list.

Comment: @RSahu ok, so a1 and a2 are allocated both in the heap and in the stack simultaneously?

Comment: @Antonio1996, no `a1` and `a2` are in stack memory. Copies of `a1` and `a2` are in heap memory. `a1` and its copy in the list are two different objects. You can modify `a1` after the call to `push_back` without affecting the copy.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I intended the “content” of a1 and a2 and not the particular instance a1 and a2.

Comment: @RSahu and for the delete, if I explicitly delete myList to avoid memory leak, automatically the copy of a1 and a2 are deleted? Or is it wrong?

Comment: @Antonio1996, that is correct.